# Gridview saving on data loses old value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get data from db. to dropdown list, if some values empty then I bind other data in `DropDownList` on row data bound. While saving `GridView` data on button click new selected values only updated. Lost old data values.

Everything works fine except lost old data value

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       PopulateLeaveAssignList();
    }
}

protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        shiftMgr = new ShiftManagerBL(BasePage.Provider, BasePage.ConnectionString);
        DataTable table = shiftMgr.GetAllShifts(userId);

        DropDownList DropDownList51 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList51");
        DropDownList DropDownList52 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList52");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["S1"].ToString()))
        {
            DropDownList51.DataSource = table;
            DropDownList51.DataBind();
            string a = dr["S1"].ToString(); 
            DropDownList51.SelectedItem.Text = dr["S1"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList51.DataSource = table;
            DropDownList51.DataTextField = "shift_title";
            DropDownList51.DataValueField = "shift_id";
            DropDownList51.DataBind();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["S2"].ToString()))
        {
            DropDownList52.DataSource = table;
            DropDownList52.DataBind();
            DropDownList52.SelectedItem.Text = dr["S2"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList52.DataSource = table;
            DropDownList52.DataTextField = "shift_title";
            DropDownList52.DataValueField = "shift_id";
            DropDownList52.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void UpdateAllCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Rs.S1 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList51") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
        Rs.S2 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList52") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
    }
}
```

I need to save old `DropDownList` value as well as newly changed value

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you were asking is about how to combine the previous shifts in the `table` variable to the newly select retrieved by `shiftMgr.GetAllShifts(userId)`, right?

Comment: @蕭為元 shiftMgr.GetAllShifts(userId) is another table data. if table one value empty  means I get data from another table

Comment: but in your if condition, no matter `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["S2"].ToString())` is true or not `DropDownList` will be assign with `table` as `DataSource` anyway; is that what you expected?

Comment: cause your elaboration is more like if true then original source else use `table` as new source.

Comment: @蕭為元 kindly update answer I struck here